# Dynamic Payment Meta Tags

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook is changing the way they accept payments and we have a table set up with information on all of the items a player can buy in the game.

These are represented with an id, a title, a description and a cost.

Since the new changes mean that you need to call a page with meta tags having the details of the item.

I've set up a page called `order.php`. This page gets the query string variable `itemId` and gets the item from the database. This is then carried on to the page like this:

```
<meta property="og:type"                   content="og:product" />
<meta property="og:title"                  content="<?PHP echo $item['title']; ?>" />
<meta property="og:plural_title"           content="<?PHP echo $item['title']; ?>" />
<meta property="og:image"                  content="http://www.slotfactory.net/scontent/images/coin.png" />
<meta property="og:description"            content="<?PHP echo $item['description']; ?>" />
<meta property="og:url"                    content="http://www.slotfactory.net/products/order.php" />
<meta property="product:price:amount"      content="<?PHP echo $item['cost']; ?>"/>
<meta property="product:price:currency"    content="USD"/>
```

When done with the URL calling order.php?itemId=1 then it returns correctly. When it's called through the facebook UI then it doesn't work. If the itemId is forced to be a certain number then it returns that item but otherwise it doesn't get the itemId variable.

```
    FB.ui({
          method: 'pay',
          action: 'purchaseitem',
          product: 'http://www.MyWebsite.com/order.php?itemId=' + itemId
        }
    );
```

Does anyone know how I am supposed to pass through a variable such as an ID? As that would be a much smaller job than all 200 table rows as their own items

Answer (score 0):

Since it had to be done fairly swiftly the only solution I found was to have a php script create a file for each ID in the database. Each page pulls the database's information related that ID so all of the data is still in the database for future edits but a new file needs to be made for each new record added

Note: I'm not marking this as the answer as it's not the solution, but I'm putting it in anyway in case someone stumbles across this looking for some way around the problem

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an htaccess url rewrite?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^order-([0-9]*)$ /order.php?itemId=$1 [L,QSA]
```

You would then call it with this url: `http://www.MyWebsite.com/order-' + itemId`

And php page order.php would receive the ID as a GET variable.